# Getting HTML Code for Website Using VBA (Not Using Selenium)

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to get the source code of a web page (internal site to our company). The site is only compatible with Chrome. It will not open on Internet Explorer. I cannot download Selenium due to IT security requirements/policies.

I would prefer to do this within VBA Excel. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you checked curl doesn't return the content you need?

Comment: I am not sure what curl is, but I will take a look.

Comment: https://www.booleanworld.com/curl-command-tutorial-examples/#Windows